# Unable to fetch Email details using perl script(using Net::IMAP::Client module)

Tags: perl, email

I have a small Perl script which has to read the content of an email. The script has to access the IMAP server in order to read the email. I'm using `Net::IMAP::Client` module to access the IMAP serve.

I'm able to access the IMAP server but unable to search the INBOX. Below is the error message displayed while trying to search the INBOX for emails:

Adding the code snippet as requested:

===============================================================

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# Use this package to make sure no undefined variables are used
use strict;

# Use the following pakages for accessing the IMAP server
use Net::IMAP::Client;
use English;

my $imap = Net::IMAP::Client->new(
server => 'My.IMAP.SERVER', 
user => 'USER_Name', 
pass => 'xxxxxxxxxx', uid_mode => 1 ) or die("Could not connect to IMAP server with error code - " . $imap->Lat_error);

$imap->login or die('Login failed: ' . $imap->last_error);
my @folders = $imap->folders;
print "the content of my mailbox are : \n";
for ( my $count=0; $count <=$#folders ; $count++ )
{
    print "$folders[$count] \n";
}

# Selecting the folder
my imap->select('INBOX'); 

# fetch all message ids (as array reference)
my $messages = $imap->search('ALL') or die("Unable to search the INBOX : " . $imap -> last_error);
print "$messages \n";
```

===============================================================

```
Unable to search the INBOX : [BADCHARSET (US-ASCII)] The specified charset is not supported. at PERL_Script.pl line xx, <GEN0> line 35.
```

Could someone please guide me in the right direction to resolve this issue.

Please let me know if any more information has to be shared.

Comment: Adding code in the question will help you to get right and quick response.

Comment: @serenesat - As requested, I've posted the complete code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Could be like an issue I had where UTF-8 wouldn't return any messages.

This was the solution. 
`$imap->search('ALL', '', 'US-ASCII')`